# How to show PDF file Inline using PDFKit in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, report, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I want to know about PDFKit code to **show the pdf inline** of any html page

I want the code 
using

**send_data()**

or **send_file()**

or **render.pdf**
{}

something like this

I am able to create the pdf file Using pdfkit but dont't know how to render it inline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a plugin in your browser that supports inline pdf rendering? I have disabled mine because I always want a download instead of inline :)